# How do I get a list of users with the Core Service?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm trying to get a list of the available users from the Core Service. I spend quite some time looking at the available service methods and the most obvious seemed to be this:

```cs
TrusteesFilterData trusteesFilterData = new TrusteesFilterData
                                        {
                                            BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.IdAndTitle,
                                            IsPredefined = false,
                                            ItemType = ItemType.User
                                        };
XElement listTrustees = client.GetSystemWideListXml(trusteesFilterData);
```

However, the code throws an error when calling GetSystemWideListXml - `Unable to create Abstract Class`. Am I using the correct approach and, if so what am I doing wrong? If not, what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the samples in the open source project for workflow notification

http://code.google.com/p/tridion-notification-framework/source/browse/NotificationService/NotificationService/Worker.cs

Lines 22 - 26 in the DoWork() method should do what you need - I think need to use `UsersFilterData` rather than `TrusteesFilterData`

```
var users = client.GetSystemWideList(new UsersFilterData { BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.IdAndTitle, IsPredefined = false });
```

Comment: Indeed, TrusteesFilterData is an abstract class that you shouldn't instantiate - as the error makes clear :)